# How to resolve @INC related issue in Perl

Tags: perl, unix

I am getting the following error, while run the perl script.

Can't locate **File/stat.pm in @INC** (you may need to install the File::stat module) (@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.24.1 /usr/local/share/perl/5.24.1 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.24 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.24 /usr/share/perl/5.24 /usr/local/lib/site_perl /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl-base) at /usr/local/share/perl/5.24.1/Path/Class/Entity.pm line 9.

I have **tried to install the missing package thorugh CPAN install**.
When i tried CPAN ,I am getting the  following error

Can't locate **File/Find.pm in @INC** (you may need to install the File::Find module) (@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.24.1 /usr/local/share/perl/5.24.1 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.24 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.24 /usr/share/perl/5.24 /usr/local/lib/site_perl /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl-base) at /usr/share/perl/5.24/CPAN/CacheMgr.pm line 8.

Can u please any one help me to resolve the issue.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Debian (Stretch) 9.9

Comment: Required packages are already installed and located in  the below path /usr/share/perl5 .  @INC array also have this path. But, still i'm getting this error.  I don't know what is missing?.

Comment: What is the absolute path for "stat.pm" file? Should be something like this: */usr/share/perl/5.24/File/stat.pm*

Comment: Find.pm has located into the path  /usr/share/perl/5.24.1/File/Find.pm , Stat.pm has located into  the below path /apps/sl-gehirn/gehirn/local/lib/perl5/Path/Class/File/Stat. pm

Comment: Well, both errors messages are right then. If you check the path for every file, is not included in any of the directories listed in the @INC array. Try to reinstall "perl-modules" package.

Comment: Reinstall package: *sudo apt-get --reinstall install perl-modules-5.24*

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193400/discussion-between-esakki-thangam-and-roberto-paz).

Answer (score 2):

File::stat has been a part of the standard Perl distribution since Perl 5.004 in 1997. There should never be a reason to install it separately. If you find yourself in that situation, then something has gone badly wrong in your Perl installation and I would strongly suggest reinstalling from scratch using the pre-built packages supplied by your Linux distribution.